# Why does Html.TextBoxFor and Html.LabelFor shows different value?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, html.textboxfor

in my following View why do i get text"name" in label and value of name in textbox?

```
    @model IEnumerable<string>

    @foreach(var names in Model)
    {
        <div class="label">@Html.LabelFor(m=>names)</div>
        <div class="input-block-level">@Html.TextBoxFor(m=>names)</div>
        <br/>
    }
```

If i run this I get following view in browser

[image]

Comment: What result are you expecting? Are you assigning values to your model that you are passing to the view?

Comment: shouldn't the label for be giving same text as textboxfor?

Comment: No, `@Html.LabelFor()` returns a `<label>`element for the _property_ while a `@Html.TextBoxFor()` looks at the _value_ of the property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Html.LabelFor` reads the metadata from a model property and displays the name of the property.
You can configure the displayed name with the `Display` or `DisplayName` attributes.
Your model has no properties, so `LabelFor` is completely useless in your example.

What do you want to achieve?
When you want to render a label with the value of the string just create a label:

```
<label>@names</label>
```